# Centralizers of non-central elements of a special group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, quotient-group

> Let $G$ be a finite group so that $\frac{G}{Z(G)}\cong \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$, where $p$ is a prime. Then $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ has the presentation $\langle aZ(G),bZ(G)|a^p ,b^p , aba^{-1}b^{-1}\in Z(G)\rangle$.
>
> I want to determine the centralizer $C_G (g)$ of an arbitrary element $g\in G\setminus Z(G)$ in term of cosets of  $Z(G)$ in $C_G (g)$, exactly.

For doing this, I take $g\in G\setminus Z(G)$. Then $Z(G)\neq gZ(G)\in \frac{G}{Z(G)}$. Every  element of $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ has the form $a^i b^j Z(G)$ for some $1\leq i\leq p$ and $1\leq j\leq p$. Especially,   I assume that $gZ(G)=a^i Z(G)$ for some $1\leq i\leq p$. So $g=a^i z$ for some $z\in Z(G)$. Then $C_G (g)=C_G (a^i z)=C_G (a^i)$. Now it is enough to compute $C_{G}(a^i )$ in term of cosets of $Z(G)$ in $C_G (a^i )$. I know that $C_G (a^i )=Z(G)\sqcup \Big(\bigsqcup_{t\in C_G (a^i)\setminus Z(G)}tZ(G)\Big)$. But I don't know for which $t$ the equation holds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already have $t=a$ obviously (and all powers of $a$ as well), and you *don't* have $t=b$ otherwise $g\in Z(G)$. You could have powers of $b$ though, I can't see why not. Perhaps $p$ being prime prevents that.

Comment: For $1 \le i < p$, we have  $\langle a,Z(G) \rangle \le C_G(a^iz) < G$, and since $|G:\langle a,Z(G) \rangle|= p$ is prime, we must have $\langle a,Z(G) \rangle = C_G(a^iz) $.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I understood the case $t=b$. But I couldn't understand why $b^j \not \in C_G (a^i )$!

Comment: @DerekHolt Why $|G:\langle a,Z(G)\rangle |=p$?

Comment: That follows from $|G/Z(G)| = p^2$ and $Z(G) = \langle aZ(G), bZ(G) \rangle$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I understood. Thank you.

Comment: @DerekHolt Why for all $i$ and $j$, $b^i \not \in C_G (a^j )$?

Comment: If $ 1 \le i <p$ and $1 \le j < p$, then $G = \langle Z(G), a^i, b^j \rangle$. If $a^i$ centralized $b^j$, then the group would be abelian.

Comment: @DerekHolt I understood. That's true. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DerekHolt You mean $G=\langle Z(G),a^i , b^j \; |\; 1\leq i<p , 1\leq j<p \rangle$ or $G=\langle Z(G),a^i , b^j \; |\; \text{for some}\; i\;  \text{and}\;  j \rangle$?

Comment: @DerekHolt Could you help me about my latter question? Thank you.